# The while loop doesn't continue as intended

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop, fgets, garbage

For some reason, the while loop in main terminates once I enter a character to search, but the intention is for you to be able to enter a line and then a character to search until you enter a blank line (enter nothing). Basically I would want to do step 1 and step 2 infinitely until I type nothing and hit enter. Why doesn't this work? Thanks anyone for help!

Also, a little side question, how do I clear any garbage after a character is entered for searching?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 41
int CharIsAt(char *pStr,char ch,int loc[],int mLoc);
int main(void){
    char array[SIZE],search;
    int found[SIZE],i,charsFound;
    //Step 1
    printf("Enter a line of text(empty line to quit): "); 
    while (fgets(array,SIZE, stdin)!=NULL && array[0]!='\n'){ //Loop until nothing is entered
    //Step 2
        printf("Enter a character to search: ");
        search=getchar();
        charsFound=CharIsAt(array,search,found,SIZE);
        printf("Entered text: ");
        fputs(array,stdout);
        printf("Character being searched for: %c\n",search);
        printf("Character found at %d location(s).\n",charsFound);
        for (i=0;i<charsFound;i++)
            printf("%c was found at %d\n",search,found[i]);
        printf("Enter a line of text(empty line to quit): ");
    }
    return 0;
}
int CharIsAt(char *pStr,char ch,int loc[],int mLoc){
    //Searches for ch in *pStr by incrementing a pointer to access
    //and compare each character in *pStr to ch.
    int i,x;
    for (i=0,x=0;i<mLoc;i++){
        if (*(pStr+i)==ch){
            //Stores index of ch's location to loc
            loc[x]=i;
            x++;    //Increment for each time ch was counted in pStr
        }
    }
    //Returns the number of times ch was found
    return x;
}
```

I included my entire code if that's not too annoying, I can try and make a simpler version of the problem if that would help. I figured posting the entire code might be more useful for answering the question.

Thanks again, cheers!

Comment: the function: `getchar()` actually returns an `int`.  Therefore, the variable `search` should be an `int` (amongst other things, then can be checking for `EOF` and should be checking for `'\n'

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the posted code only prompts the user once for a line of input (and seems to expect the user to be able to 'mind read' the program to know when they are expected to enter the next line to be searched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   while (fgets(array,SIZE, stdin)!=NULL && array[0]!='\n'){
        printf("Enter a character to search: ");
        search=getchar();
        charsFound=CharIsAt(array,search,found,SIZE);
        printf("Entered text: ");
        fputs(array,stdout);
        printf("Character being searched for: %c\n",search);
        printf("Character found at %d location(s).\n",charsFound);
        for (i=0;i<charsFound;i++)
            printf("%c was found at %d\n",search,found[i]);
        if (fgets(array,SIZE, stdin)==NULL) break;
    }
    return 0;
```

This should work

Comment: nope, will not work, the newline sequence from the user entering the `search` char is still in `stdin`, so the last call to `fgets()` will always be successful

Answer (score 1):

the main problem with the posted code is that the user had to press `enter` to get the `search` character into the program.  However, the call to `getchar()` only consumes a single char, so it did not consume the newline sequence.

To fix this problem, call `getchar()` in a loop until the char is either EOF or '\n'  to empty `stdin` of any/all leftover trash.

Then step back to the top of the loop